# DOORS attribute not working as expected

Tags: ibm-doors, ibm-rational

I found this code, which worked well IN SHAREABLE EDIT:

```
// Attribute DXL for locked objects
if (isLockedByUser(obj))
{
obj.attrDXLName = "LOCKED"
}
```

and added:

```
else
{
obj.attrDXLName = "unlocked"
}
```

but the `else` condition doesn't work (the `if` part functions the same). What am I missing? First time coding in DXL, but I have C experience. EDIT: I figured out the `else` condition probably can't be updated in an unlocked item, so it will never appear.

The remaining question is, Why doesn't it work for Exclusive Edit? Should I check the module for `isLockedByUser`, instead, because it's locked at that level?

```
// Attribute DXL for locked objects
if (isLockedByUser(obj) or isLockedByUser(current))
{
obj.attrDXLName = "LOCKED"
}
```

... which doesn't work, either. Again, it works for Shareable Edit, but not for Exclusive Edit.

Suggestions on how to get this field to work for Exclusive Edit?

Answer (score 0):

In the DXL Reference Manual (Chapter 36: General Functions > Locking) for isLockedByUser, here's how it is described:

> bool isLockedByUser(Object o)
>
> Returns true if the specified object is locked by the current user when in edit shareable mode. Otherwise, returns false.
>
> This function is not equivalent to checking whether the current user can modify the given object.

My guess (I haven't dealt with locking via DXL myself) is that isLockedByUser only has meaning when the module is in shared edit mode, so you might have to find another way to do what you're trying to do.